# Does checking for API request limit in a POST service method violate REST?

Tags: rest, google-apps-script

I'm working on a Google Script REST API that uses Google's `MailApp.sendEmail` method. That method, like many others in their APIs has a hard limit on the number of requests you can send it per day.

My API consists of one method that simply sends a contact email. Of course, it handles a POST request to do this. Does checking for the number of allotted requests, returning an HTTP error if the limit has been reached, sending the message otherwise, violate the statelessness requirement of REST?

Comment: Every one of Google's REST APIs will return an http error if out of quota, so why not yours too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does checking for the number of allotted requests, returning an HTTP error if the limit has been reached, sending the message otherwise, violate the statelessness requirement of REST?

No.

The first piece of evidence is that we have a status code specifically for that situation: [RFC 6585](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6585#section-4) defines [429 Too Many Requests](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6585#section-4).

> The 429 status code indicates that the user has sent too many
> requests in a given amount of time ("rate limiting").

The second piece of evidence is in Fielding's Thesis, where he defines precisely what he means by [stateless](https://www.ics.uci.edu/%7Efielding/pubs/dissertation/net_arch_styles.htm#sec_3_4_3):

> Each request from client to server must contain all of the information necessary to understand the request